# Delete worksheets if cells below specified strings are empty

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a script which will cycle through the worksheets in my workbook and delete the worksheet if the cells directly under the strings "detected", "not detected" and "other" are empty. If there is something entered under any of the three strings the worksheet shouldn't be deleted.

I have some code (below) which will delete the worksheet if a specific cell is empty, but I need to integrate a piece to FIND any of the three strings (if they are there, they will be in column A), and to offset this to check whether the cell below is empty.

```
Sub DeleteEmptyWorksheets()

Dim MySheets As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each MySheets In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     If MySheets.Range(“A1”) = “” Then
     MySheets.Delete

End If

Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

The script will be used in processing COVID19 test results, so if you can help it will be extra karma points!!

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a code that should assist you.

```
Sub DeleteEmptyWorksheets()
Dim MySheets As Worksheet
Dim rngTest As Range
Dim arTest
Dim blNBFound As Boolean

arTest = Array("detected", "not detected", "other")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each MySheets In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    blNBFound = False
    For i = LBound(arTest) To UBound(arTest)
        Set rngTest = MySheets.Range("A:A").Find(arTest(i))
        If Not rngTest Is Nothing Then
            If Len(rngTest.Offset(1, 0)) > 0 Then
                blNBFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    If blNBFound = False Then MySheets.Delete
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```